# Why isn't the y-coordinate property updating?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

I've been using CodeCombat for learning. With this code here I've been stuck for a week and nobody can help me. I'm trying to understand why the Y-coordinate property (particularly hero.pos.y) isn't updating. I'm talking about this part:

```
else if (hero.pos.y === 24) {//works only when x===18
hero.say("moving to the steel door");
...
}
```

It doesn't register as changed although my hero moves to the position x:18 y:24. Everyone who's willing to help is welcome to reply.

```
hero.moveXY(18, 40);
while (true) {
hero.say("starting while");
var enemy = hero.findNearestEnemy();
var friend = hero.findNearestFriend();
var item = hero.findNearestItem();
if (enemy) {
   ...do smth
} else if (friend) {
   ...do smth
} else if (item) {
    ...do smth
} else if (hero.pos.y === 40) {//this works
    hero.say("moving down");
    hero.moveXY(hero.pos.x, hero.pos.y - 16); //this works
    hero.say("At this point I SHOULD have changed my hero.pos.y to 24");
} else if (hero.pos.y === 24) {//this works only with x===18
    hero.say("moving to the steel door");
} else if (hero.pos.y !== 24) {//so this runs even when I check hero.pos, which is 24!
    hero.say("My Y-position hasn't changed!");
}
```

}

*Now please note it's an Online game, meaning obviously I didn't create the code from scratch and if you're not coding in the game environment you can't validate it.

Comment: Have you tried right before `hero.moveXY()` adding: `hero.pos.y = hero.pos.y - 16;`?

Comment: If you are referring to the else if (hero.pos.y === 24) statement, yes I tried adding it and it didn't work. I want to understand why the code that I already have doesn't work.

Comment: Just a tip - can you try reproduce the problem in the a really small piece of code? Most people don't want to read through all of this code to try solve your problem.

Comment: I see no code to modify `y`.

Comment: yes. done, thank you.

Comment: No, not done. Present your [MCVE].